# Change the collection view cell size

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I want to resize `FSCalendar`'s date frame size, which is inside the `collectionView` cell.

Please help me change the collection view cell size in `FSCalendar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function after adding UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
         return CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenWidth)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use UICollectionView Delegate Methods for changing height and width of CollectionView

in Swift

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, transitionLayoutForOldLayout fromLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, newLayout toLayout: UICollectionViewLayout) -> UICollectionViewTransitionLayout


func setCollectionViewLayout(_ layout: UICollectionViewLayout, animated: Bool)
```